# Nunjucks: Passing an object as parameter in macro

Tags: macros, prototype, templating, nunjucks

I'd like to create some nested macros. One for a section, and in there I'd like to call the macro of any component dynamically. (In this case the component I want to call is `article`.)

Here's my section macro:

```
  <!-- section.nunjucks -->
  {% macro section(config) %}
    <section class="site__section section">
      {% for item in config %}
        {{ item.macro(item.settings) }}
      {% endfor %}
    </section>
  {% endmacro %}
```

Component macro:

```
  <!-- article.nunjucks -->
  {% macro article(settings) %}
    <article class="article {{ settings.classes }}">
      <h1 class="article__title">Hello World</h1>
      <p class="article__body">Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
    </article>
  {% endmacro %}
```

And i'm trying to call it here:

```
{{ section([{'macro': article, 'settings': {'classes': 'article--large'}}]) }}
```

I get a syntax error for this bit: `'settings': {'classes': 'article--large'}`

How can I pass in `settings.classes` as a parameter, when calling my `settings` macro?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I just have found out, spaces matter in Nunjucks. So writing

```
{{ section([{ 'macro': article, 'settings': { 'classes': 'article--large' } }]) }}
```

instead, will actually run without any syntax errors.